# ImportError: No module named anorm

Tags: python, importerror

I got the below shown error. Can anyone please help me with a solution?

```
from common import anorm, getsize
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
   from common import anorm, getsize
ImportError: cannot import name anorm
```

Comment: It seems you don't have the ``common`` package installed or it doesn't have a function called ``anorm``. Does ``import common`` work?

Comment: The error isn't `no module named common`, so I assume it does.

Comment: import common works @JaredAndrews

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for necroposting, but for anyone who's stuck on this:

apparently, you're trying to run the `opencv` example somewhat like [this one](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/find_obj.py). You need to copy the [common.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/common.py) from the same directory as well and everything would be fine (no need to install `common` package which has nothing to do with this partucular problem).

Answer (score 0):

The `common` module does not contain an importable item named `anorm`.  Simple as that.

Some possible reasons why:

1. The `common` module was not installed correctly.
2. Misspelling of the name of the item to be imported.
3. A file named `common.py` exists in the current directory, which takes precedence over the real `common` module (wherever it is).
4. Circular imports (which don't appear to be the case here, given the error traceback).

Comment: I uninstalled and re-installed common but still it shows the same error

Comment: Without access to the code we can't tell you whether it's reasonable to expect it to contain `anorm`. Is the source available somewhere? Can you please update the question to show us why you think it should work?

Comment: Another common error is assuming `from thing import other` to work when in reality you need to do `from thing.thing import other` if the module isn't set up to expose its internal namespace.

Comment: m = (anorm(p1 - (x, y)) < r) | (anorm(p2 - (x, y)) < r)

Comment: that is where i require the usage of anorm

Comment: That doesn't really tell us anything about the ``common`` module. Is the source code available somewhere? @tripleee's suggestion is also a good one, trying ``from common.common import anorm`` may solve your issue.

Comment: I got my problem solved. As mentioned by @John Gordon common.py was missing

Comment: After running  common.py import anorm is possible. But when run along with the entire core same error occurs.